# Reassigning a variable in list comprehension

Tags: functional-programming, list-comprehension, elixir

I'm new to Elixir and functional programming coming from OO background.

I'm stuck trying to understand how variable reassignment works in Elixir in list comprehension. I expected functions test1() and test2() to print 4, but test2() doesn't reassign variable and prints 1.

```
defmodule SampleCode do
  def test1 do
    num = 1
    num = num + 1
    num = num + 2
    IO.puts num # Prints 4
  end

  def test2 do
    num = 1
    for i <- (1..2) do
      num = num + i
    end
    IO.puts num # Prints 1
  end
end
```

1. Why do they these functions behave differently?
2. Is this a variable scoping thing in Elixir or a basic principle in functional programming that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm rather sure it's just scoping (read `num2 = num+i`) - btw: things like `num = num + 1` are a anti-pattern in FP as this makes no sense without rebinding values

Comment: What's the right way to implement this if `num = num + 1` is frowned upon in FP? Recursion? The code in question is a very simplified version of something else I tried to do, so it's not as trivial as it looks :)

Comment: yes - on a primitive level recursion - or things like folds later - in this simplified case of course you would just say `result = 1+1+2` or simply `result=4` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a variable scoping thing in Elixir or a basic principle in functional programming that I'm missing?

It is both actually.

Elixir allows rebinding only in the same scope and all constructs, with the exception of `case`, `cond` and `receive`, introduce a new scope. Some examples:

```
num = 1

try do
  num = 2
after
  num = 3
end

num #=> 1
```

Funs:

```
num = 1
(fn -> num = 2 end).()
num #=> 1
```

Now some examples of the exceptions to the rule:

```
num = 1
case true do
  true -> num = 2
end
num #=> 2

num = 1
cond do
  true -> num = 2
end
num #=> 2
```

Even though, the cases above are somewhat discouraged as it is preferable to return the value explicitly:

```
num = 1
case x do
  true  -> 2
  false -> num
end
#=> will return 1 or 2
```

The example above makes explicit what are the values being returned from case. Why those are supported in Elixir, even though not recommended, is a long story that has its origin in Erlang and continued due to some of the (very few) imperative macros in Elixir like `if` and `unless`. It will likely change as we move towards Elixir 2.0.

The best way to perform what you want is via the functions in `Enum`. Your particular example could be done with `Enum.sum/1` but any other complex example can be implemented with `Enum.reduce/3` (almost all functions in Enum are implemented in terms of reduce, which may be fold in other languages).

Answer (score 4):

To understand what happened, take a look at what elixir does to your code to syntactically allow rebinding, when the language* does not support it:

```
         BEFORE                         AFTER

defmodule SampleCode do     |  defmodule SampleCode do
  def test1 do              |    def test1 do
    num = 1                 |      num_1 = 1
    num = num + 1           |      num_2 = num_1 + 1
    num = num + 2           |      num_3 = num_2 + 2
    IO.puts num # Prints 4  |      IO.puts num_3
  end                       |    end
                            |
  def test2 do              |    def test2
    num = 1                 |      num_1 = 1
    for i <- (1..2) do      |      for i <- (1..2) do
      num = num + i         |        num_2 = num_1 + i
    end                     |      end
    IO.puts num # Prints 1  |      IO.puts num_1
  end                       |    end
end                         |  end
```

*Elixir's foundation is Erlang-  Elixir's compilation produces Erlang .beam files, to be executed by the Erlang Virtual Machine.  Erlang does NOT allow variable rebinding, so **Elixir swaps out your variable names during compilation**.

If you want to up your FP game quite a bit, and give yourself a tremendous leg up in writing Elixir, I would recommend forcing yourself to learn the Erlang syntax, and write strictly Erlang solutions to your problems for a month or few before going back to Elixir.

In case you are curious what actually happened to your code, here's the actual Erlang generated by Elixir:

```
1: test1() ->
2:     num@1 = 1,
3:     num@2 = num@1 + 1,
4:     num@3 = num@2 + 2,
5:    'Elixir.IO':puts(num@3).
6: test2() ->
7:     num@1 = 1,
8:     'Elixir.Enum':reduce(#{'__struct__' => 'Elixir.Range',
9:             first => 1, last => 2},
10:          [], fun (i@1, _@1) -> num@2 = num@1 + i@1 end),
11:    'Elixir.IO':puts(num@1).
```

Especially note line 11- the only variable it references is `num@1`, which in Erlang cannot be altered by lines 8-10- no matter what happens in there, the value bound to `num@1` is still `1`, because that's how it is first bound on line 7.

Comment: Just one note: it is less about Erlang not supporting multiple assignments but more about where Erlang imposes a new scope. The difference is also clear in Erlang: when you are inside a new scope, a new variable won't be accessible from outside. And the snippet that shows what Elixir compiles to is neat. :)

Comment: @JoséValim: Looking at it again, my disassembly is slightly off, as the Erlang variables came out lower-cased. I can't take any credit for it thou- original source was someone else, and I'm pretty sure they got it from the example [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/beam_lib.html#debug_info)